# Vscode switch text cases with only one keybinding shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

VSCode already exists Tramform Command for keybinding but I can't set dupliticate shortcut for switching each case.

Just like in MS-Word, the shortcut for changing between text cases is Shift + F3.
Is there any configuration or macro script or any way to set up shortcut VSCode just like that?

[image]

Comment: You want to cycle through the commands on the same text?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I want to transform each case for selected text with the same shortcut each time pressing.

Comment: I'm still confused. can you give and exact and fully spelled out explanation of what you want your keyboard shortcut to do?

Comment: In that case, the `Toggle Case` mentioned by @JehongAhn looks like what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about these extensions?

#### [toggle toggle - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tuweifeng.toggleToggle)

This gives you two types of toggles.

1. lower vs UPPER
2. CamelCase vs snake_case

#### [Toggle Case - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PranshuAgrawal.toggle-case)

This can toggle text through variant cases.

Comment: I've just tried both and the Toggle Case extension is exactly what I needed. Thank you!